# Is the advice "don't operate light switches barefoot" outdated?

Tags: electrical, grounding, safety

I was taught in my young age (1980s-1990s) not to operate light switches (or anything electrical) barefoot. Is this advice still relevant in 2021 (in a modern house in Western Europe with grounding, just to have a reference)?

Or does it no longer apply to modern wiring and light switches?

Comment: That's not advice I was ever given as a kid in the US in the 70s. Interested to hear the responses. What kind of flooring did you have in your house when you were young?

Comment: I thought you were not supposed to drive a car barefooted. Where are you in the world?

Comment: Think I would be more worried about walking on a Lego piece in barefeet.

Comment: Depends on the quality of the switches / insulation. Clearly based around inadequately insulated switches (aggravated by 220-250V being typical.) Visiting in Scotland, nearly all lightswitches were pull-string operated, so the habit of avoiding direct contact with possibly poorly insulated switches was clearly deeply engrained in habit or code.

Comment: @FreeMan Tiles. It was a 1960s house (but of course the wiring was newer). I was born in 1983, for reference.

Comment: @Ed Beal  Just googled, seems like barefoot driving is legal in all 50 states.

Comment: @EdBeal I meant light switches in a house, not in a car. This may be a translation/word choice issue.

Comment: Primarily (but not exclusively) Americans answering questions 'round here, so you may not get a particularly satisfactory answer. Do hang out, though, lots of Europeans do answer, so you may get something. (Also, the driving reference was tangential to the question, not a misunderstanding.)

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the warning! Are European and American electrical systems and safety measures so different? I would have guessed they were quite similar.

Comment: What we do differs somewhat significantly from what they do in the UK, plus there's that whole 120v vs 240v residential wiring difference. Beyond that, I'll leave it to the electricians.

Comment: Do know it is recommended to wear good footwear when working on electric panel/s cables, but half of that is so your feet are protected from sharp things going into them or dropping a hammer on them.  Only thing from light switches should be static electricity.

Comment: FYI, you can also swim after eating and run with scissors. It's liberation day.

Comment: @crip659 I am a few months older than you are. I had a friend get a ticket for driving without shoes, I grew up on the west coast a friend was cited for driving without shoes after rear ending another car. He ended up in traffic school and missed a wrestling tournament is the main reason I remember it.

Comment: At least some states, and probably all, require "appropriate footwear" to drive.  This is a holdover from when all cars had manual transmission and clutches, and wearing flip flops or heels could genuinely be dangerous.  Cars have changed but the rules are still there and if a cop tickets you for driving barefoot, and you show up in a typical Dukes-of-Hazard style local American courtroom trying to get out of it by saying your car has automatic transmission, you don't stand a chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the advice was particularly salient in the 80's or even decades before. I think it was based on some irrational fear &/or misconception.

Don't use light switches with wet hands - which is why bathrooms have pull-switches. That makes sense, but to extrapolate that to any & all light switches for fear they're badly wired, unearthed & the shoes will stop you becoming the route to earth… sorry, that's irrational fear.

It belongs in the same category as always making sure socket switches are off if nothing is plugged in, which still sees some adherents even in the UK, where you'd need a slim screwdriver to even open the socket gates be able to poke something into one.

Comment: When I was a kid our bathrooms had regular switches. But if the toaster was plugged in wrong no socks and touch it you got a buzz, socks on or plugged in right no buzz.

Comment: Ouch!! I live in the UK. You simply cannot "plug something in wrong." Plugs go one way & one way only. All sockets are earthed. If a potential to ground issue occurred, it would trip the circuit (back in the old days on fuse-wire, probably with enough of a reminder to never do that again;) I've had bathrooms with regular switches - my current one does, as it was converted from a bedroom, so is technically 'not to code'.

Comment: Tetsujin This is very old electrical 2 prong non polarized. polarized receptacles were first called out in 1962 in the NEC (I did have to look that up). The big difference is our voltage is lower so depend on conditions we may not get a shock when you would. For example when I was working general construction I had thick callous on my hands not only could I pick up hot things but I was affected less by shocks.  Now my apprentice do all the heavy pipe work and I feel the shocks more when they happen.

Answer (score 3):

It's relevant to older housing stock, especially where circuits *which were ungrounded* were extended with grounded wire and that ground was hooked up.  This can create an "island of grounds" in the addition area, in which all the addition grounds are connected *to each other*, but not connected back to the panel.

In this scenario, current leakage from *any connected device* will not be neutralized, because there is no path from ground back to the panel.  Instead, all the grounds in the connected "island of grounds" will be floated up toward line voltage!  And yeah, you could get nailed by the switch plate cover screws.  The risk expands here because all it takes is for any device in the island to have a ground fault, and they're all lit up.

The risk is somewhat expanded for Europeans. They use 240V like the Americans, except Americans center-ground (like the Filipinos do) so it is 2 hot legs with only 120V to ground.  In fact, the 120V is used directly for small appliances.    In Europe, the 230V is only one of three legs of 3-phase power (400V "wye"), so any leg of power is 230V to ground.  It's about 83% of American 277V 3-phase power (480V "wye"), which is industrial and treated with [great fear and respect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY).

Comment: My uncle has an old A frame cabin made in the 50s.   I am sure nothing is grounded.   There is a main room on the bottom floor with a light switch next to a sliding glass door which I am guessing took moisture.   We flick on that switch with reverence knowing we will get a couple amps - we even have the smaller kids go over and hit it if they don't believe us!

Comment: Europeans use 230-240V for everything but their largest appliances, which are 400V 3ph

Comment: @DMoore - if you got a "couple amps" you'd be dead!

Comment: Much less than 1 amp will cause fibrillation of the heart. Around 0.075 amps can do it.

Comment: For that matter, 0.01 amps (10ma) can knock you silly, and that kills you too if the drowning or the fall kills you.  Drowning is especially tragic, because people's habit is to jump in after drowning people.